# "Continuously differentiable"

Tags: calculus

I'm struggling to understand the term.

"A function is continuously differentiable of order $k$ at $a$ if the $k$-th derivative of $f$ exists and is continuous on some open interval containing $a$."

$(1)$ Does this mean that a function is continuously differentiable if the $k$-th derivative exists AND $f^{'}$ is continuous on some open interval containing $a.$

OR

$ (2)$ Does this mean that a function is continuously differentiable if the $k$-th derivative exists AND $f$ is continuous on some open interval containing $a.$

So if I have to show if a function is continuously differentiable of order $2$ at $a$ I would need to show that $f''$ exists and $f'$ is continuous?

If anyone could provide me an concrete example with a simple one-variable function that would be appreciated.

Comment: Keep in mind that if a function is differentiable then it's automatically continuous.

Answer (score 4):

It means that the k'th derivative of $f$ exists in an open interval of $a$ and that k'th derivative is a continuous function in that open interval.

Answer (score 1):

Example: If $k \geq 1$ is an integer, the function
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
  0 & \text{if $x < 0$,} \\
  x^{k+1} & \text{if $x \geq 0$,}\end{cases}
$$
is $k$ times, but not $(k+1)$ times, continuously differentiable.

Comment: Sorry but could you elaborate on that to exactly why? Thanks.

Comment: Let's call the function $f_k$ instead of $f$. The derivative $f_k'$ is proportional to $f_{k-1}$; calculating $f_k'(0)$ requires difference quotients (i.e., the definition), but is straightforward. Sketch the graphs of $f_0$ and $f_1$, then do induction on $k$.